# Longer stem, need to re-cable?

Tags: bike-fit, cable, stem

When I got my bike built, I chose a 60mm-long stem. It's a single-speed bike with front and rear cantilever break (cyclocross model.) After riding on the bike for a couple of months, I have decided the stem is too short and I want to replace it with a stem that's 100mm long.

Is it likely that I can easily swap the two stems, or will I have to mount longer cables for the brakes?

[image: Here is a picture of the cockpit]

Comment: Is what is shown in the image a pretty good indication of how much cable is left over? To me it looks like it could be close, do you think you have an additional 40mm of cable? If it were me i think i would order the cables as well, try the install and if their to tight install new cables. Otherwise just save em for later when you need to replace them anyway.

Comment: Measure out how far 40mm more will put your bar, undo the faceplate clamps on the stem and pull the bar 40mm out and observe the cables at this distance, you should be able to guess at that point. You don't want them so tight you can't turn lol

Comment: Theres a decent chance you'll have to put longer cables. In any case, if you have the stem, the stem swap is a 5 minute job, then you can check if the cables are [long enough](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cables.html#routing). If they're too short, replace them.

Comment: thank you for the comments! I asked the question because I don't know whether I should order the stem and replace it myself (cheaper) or buy it from the bike shop and get it mounted there. You're right though, it all depends on how much cable is left. I'll test it by removing the faceplace clamps on the stem, and I will also take a better picture and post it here.

Comment: The front will be fine, it's a lateral move for that one. For the rear brake...rotate the bars to their max, is the cable about to bind or does it have a lot of room left? That should start to answer your question.

Comment: I suspect if you go into a bike shop and say "I have a new stem, but now I need new cables and bar tape" they will be happy to oblige. They make money out of selling the mechanic's time, and that's a reasonable amount of time to sell :) Or you could take this chance to learn a bunch more about bike maintenance and do the work yourself. A tip: buy some really cheap bar tap to use the first time. You will almost certainly stuff it up, so having a "practice roll" is worth while.

Comment: @Móż I know already how to replace bar tapes, I did it many times already on my road bike, and yes, the first couple of times I f*cked up some good expensive Cinelli tape :) How difficult is to replace cables? That's something I have never done. Should I get "practice cables" as well? :)

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino no, cables are harder to damage - if you're being cautious you can cut them a 5cm longer than you think, fit them, once you are confident you can cut the extra off and re-fit (because that only involves the brake/derailleur end of the cables so it's simple to do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went from a 60mm to a 100mm stem and there was no need to re-route the cables. As pointed out in the comments (thank you all for the comments!), this is not general and it really depends on how much cable there is. Fortunately in my case, there was enough.

On a related note, I had to add a spacer on top of the stem, because the new stem is lower than the one I had beforehand.